# Tkinter in Anaconda Spyder

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, anaconda, spyder

[image]So I just installed Anaconda Spyder, until this point I used the original vanilla Python. There I have learned to draw object etc. I tried to do the same here, just draw a simple rectangle, however after I run the progrem, the canvas doesn't appeares like it used to in Python. What could be the problem?

```
import tkinter
canvas=tkinter.Canvas(width=500,height=500)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_rectangle(200,200,300,300)
```

These lines work in Python but not in Spyder, why?

Comment: There's a typo in `cnavas`. Do I assume that's not in your actual code?

Comment: No, that is not, but I'll correct it.

Comment: I suspect it is because when you are running spyder you are using PyQt and that may be the root cause of the problem. I know drawing with matplotlib does not work when using TkAgg but works with Qt5Agg because of this reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think that happens because you are not showing a window
Try

```
mywindow=tkinter.Tk()
mywindow.mainloop()
```

and you should see your rectangle.